# How can I display a pdf\jpg file in a new page using Blob when AdBlock extension is install in the browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to download a file from the server and using Blob to display this file in a new tab, but the AdBlock extension is blocking the browser.

```
this.documentsService.downloadFiles(fileName).subscribe(file => {
            let newBlob;

            if(file.filename.match('.pdf')) {
                newBlob = new Blob([file ], { type: "application/pdf" });
            } else {
                newBlob = new Blob([file ], { type: "image/jpg" });
            }

            const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);

            window.open(data, '_blank');
        });
```